# Neo4j lazy loading with c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, neo4j, lazy-loading

Iam creating a social network using neo4j , I work with Microsoft azure servives , and I wrote my backend at c# , I am connecting the database with an IOS/Android app so at some point I need to lazy load the entities , how can I do that in c# ?? I so some solves but for Java , is there any for c# ???

Answer (score 0):

See http://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet for available .Net libraries.

Your iOS / Android part should be unrelated.

Comment: I know that my applicatin should be unrelated , can you direct me to a specific library which helps ?